# $modalInstance in ui.bootstrap 0.12 not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui

I am using JQuery 1.3.8 with ui.bootstrap Version: 0.12.0.

When i use `$modalInstance`in controller my page does not load but if i remove it, the page works fine but modal commands don't work.

My code:

```
angularFormsApp.controller('efController',
function efController($scope, $window, $routeParams, $modalInstance ,DataService) {

    if ($routeParams.id)
        $scope.employee = DataService.get_employee($routeParams.id);
    else
        $scope.employee = { id: 0 };

    //$scope.employee = DataService.employee;

    $scope.editableEmployee = $scope.employee;

    $scope.departments = [
        "Engineering",
                "Management",
                "Finance",
                "IT"
    ];

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        if ($scope.editableEmployee.id = 0) {
            DataService.insertEmployee($scope.editableEmployee);
        }
        else {
            DataService.updateEmployee($scope.editableEmployee);
        }


        $scope.employee = angular.copy($scope.editableEmployee);
        //$window.history.back();
        $modalInstance.close();

    };

    $scope.cancelForm = function () {
        //$window.history.back();
        alert($modalInstance);
        $modalInstance.dismiss();

    };

});
```

Code where i am using open method:
angularFormsApp.controller("HomeController",
    function ($scope, $location, $modal ,DataService) {

```
    $scope.showCreateEmployeeForm = function () {

        //$location.path('/newEmployeeForm');
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "app/EmployeeForm/efTemplate.html",
            controller: "efController"
        });

    };

    $scope.showUpdateEmployeeForm = function (id) {
        $location.path('/updateEmployeeForm/'+ id );
    };

});
```

Please help me here why the page does not load. I am using MVC template of .NET.

Comment: Please show your code that is creating thr $modalInstance by calling $modal.open()in your resolve method. If you don't have such a method and are just trying to inject $modalInstance, then that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Did you included **BootStrap Dependency** in your Module Configuration like above code,it's necessary
   to add when we are using Boot Strap please checkit

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, I included.                                                         var angularFormsApp = angular.module('angularFormsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])